# R-package building with devtools::build_win(): Version contains large components (0.0.0.9000)

Tags: r

I'm reading Hadley Wickham's R Packages book to make my first R package and submitted my package to be built on a Windows machine using `devtools::build_win()`.  As recommended in the book, I'm trying eliminate all NOTES so that I have a smooth CRAN submission experience.  I can't get rid of this NOTE, and it is my only NOTE remaining (I have no ERRORS or WARNINGS):

```
Version contains large components (0.0.0.9000)
```

What does large components mean?  How do I get winbuild to get rid of this NOTE?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two things:  the NOTE is due to your package being a first submission.  Looking at win-builder's `00check.log` you might see:

```
* checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... NOTE
Maintainer: 'First Last <first.last@email.com>'

New submission

Version contains large components (0.0.0.9000)
```

Change the version number in your DESCRIPTION file such that none of the individual components of the version (`major.minor.patch.etc`) are [greater than or equal to 1234](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/c40eb16072ae3c8fe0f9817a20e1a37e412e9704/src/library/tools/R/QC.R#L6547-L6548), perhaps to 0.1.0, getting rid of the fourth component.  This will remove the `Version contains large components (0.0.0.9000)` but the NOTE will remain because it is your first submission of the package.